# How to rotate object only one side

Tags: ios, objective-c, transform, cgcontext

i have already rotate success from center point.
But its not rotate from one side.
for ex,
When i have select point A & rotate then its rotate from Only A side,not from Point B side.
 When i have select point B & rotate then its rotate from Only B side,not from Point A side.

I have already set anchor point but its not work.

[image]

Code Like that:

```
CGFloat angle = [self pointPairToBearingDegrees:frspnt secondPoint:lastpnt];
CGAffineTransform newtrans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( angle * M_PI ) / 180 );
[sender.superview layer].anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.1);
sender.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(sender.superview.transform, newtrans);
```

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to rotate the whole red view or it's parts? What do you mean by simultaneous rotation around two points?

Comment: Yes i will rotate Whole red part, but only one side

Comment: Please update your question with all method that are using for animation and ya clear your question with what kind of task you want to perform .

Comment: i mean Rotate imageview object, i already rotate object but its rotate from object's center.

Now , i rotate that object from x,y position if i select end of object point,
else i rotate from end point if i select start point

Comment: are you understand?